# Does Highcharts automatically render new XHR CSV columns?

Tags: highcharts

Is it expected behavior that Highcharts will automatically render new **data.csv** columns received via **XHR**, without ANY new JS code for new yAxis[] or series[] elements?

I started with a working chart with 3 visible yAxis spline series plus one xAxis time series and two invisible yAxis series.

I **added code** to the server-side SQL to return an extra 7 columns in the CSV response.

I **did not add** any code to the client-side Highchart JS.

However, all the new columns appeared **LIKE MAGIC** AS visible plots!

Never mind that the colors, etc, aren't exactly what I want... how did Highcharts not (a) **ignore** the new columns or (b) **crash**?

SAP SQL Anywhere server side...

```
SELECT STRING ( 
'Sample Recorded At,CPU Percent,Index Adds,Commits,Sampling Id,Sample Set Number,Active Req,Bytes,Disk Reads,Executing Conns,Max Conn CPU,Requests,Sample Time', 
'\x0d\x0a',
LIST ( 
STRING ( DATEFORMAT ( subset.sample_recorded_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' ),
',',
CAST ( subset.interval_CPU_percent AS DECIMAL ( 30, 1 ) ), 
',',
etcetera
```

Browser side...

```
chartOptions.data.csv = chartXHR.responseText;
```

Comment: I think that adding this logic into the `exportData` callback might be a solution: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.exportData

Comment: @SebastianWędzel No solution is required because it is not a problem... it is a question about expected behavior... the observed behavior is quite magical, in fact :)